# Using RegEx to find a string (as variable number)

Tags: php, regex

How can I find numbers inside certain strings in php?

For example, having this text inside a page, I would like to find for

`|||12345|||`
or
`|||354|||`

I'm interested in the numbers, they always change according to the page I visit (numbers being the id of the page and 3-5 characters length).

So the only thing I know for sure is those pipes surrounding the numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `(?<=\|{3})\d{3,5}(?=\|{3})` https://regex101.com/r/W8jLmo/2

Comment: thanks, it will be usefull in my path to learn this. i check your code and i think it will be usefull. but the string is not know for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @S.Kablar's suggestion is pretty valid, it makes use of a syntax that may be difficult for a beginner.

The more casual way to achieve your goal would be as follows:

```
$text = 'your input string';
if (preg_match_all('~\|{3}(\d+)\|{3}~', $text, $matches)) {
    foreach($matches[1] as $number) {
        var_dump($number); // prints smth like string(3) "345"
    }
}
```

The breakdown of the regex:

- `~` and `~` surround the expression
- `\|` stands for the pipe, which is a special character in regex and must be escaped with a backslash
- `{3}` says 'the previous (the pipe) must be present exactly three times'
- `(` and `)` enclose a subpattern so that it is stored under `$matches[1]`
- `\d` requires a digit
- `+` says 'the previous (a digit) may be repeated but must have at least one instance'

Comment: thanks for the explanation. so far i get this explanation how regex works... however the only thing i know for $text is |||xxx||| where those xxx are unknow for me. before having $text...

ill grab a url in php, searc for the string ,and find what its inside those 6 pipes. and finally Save it in a variable $text. after having $text i would like to find the numbers XD

Comment: Do you have your problem solved? If not, what it is that doesn't work for you? Can you narrow down the question, please?

Comment: nope, sorry, not solved. ill try to explain in more details(sorry for my english).

|||23654|||   <--this is the string i want to locate, numbers generated according to the url, like id's

lets say i have to read a url, for example this very url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531752/using-regex-to-find-a-string-as-variable-number

and im trying to find

Answer (score 3):

Using this `\|\|\|\K\d{3,5}(?=\|\|\|)`
gives many advantages.

https://regex101.com/r/LtbKfM/1

1. First, three literals without a quantifier is a simple strncmp() c
   call.   Also, anytime a regex starts with an *assertion* it is
   inherently slower.   Therefore, this is the fastest match for the 3
   leading pipe symbols.
2. Second, using the `\K` construct excludes whatever was previously
   matched from group 0.   We don't want to get the 3 pipes in the
   match, but we do want to match them.

**edit**

> Note that capture group results are not stored in a special string
>   buffer.
>   Each group is really a pointer (or offset) and a length.
>   The pointer (or offset) is to somewhere in the source string.
>   When it comes time to extract a particular group string, the overload   function for braces
>   `matches[#]` uses the pointer (or offset) and length to create and return a string instance.
>   Using the `\K` construct simply sets the group 0 pointer (or offset)
>   to the position    in the string that represents the position that
>   matched after the `\K` construct.

3. Third, using a lookahead assertion for 3 pipe symbols does not
   consume   the symbols as far as the next match is concerned.   This
   makes these symbols available for the next match.   I.e:
   |||`999`|||`888`||| would get 2 matches as would
   |||`999`|||||`888`|||.

The result is an array of just the numbers.

Formatted

```
 \|\|\|                # 3 pipe symbols
 \K                    # Exclude previous items from the match (group 0)
 \d{3,5}               # 3-5 digits
 (?= \|\|\| )          # Assertion, not consumed, 3 pipe symbols ahead
```

Comment: there is only 1 instance of |||numbers||| in the entire page XD, thats what i use it as id in this format.

Comment: @JacielLv - Hey no offence, I'm just here to educate people. `there is only 1 instance of |||numbers||| in the entire page XD, thats what i use it as id in this format` if that's the case, then this regex is not for you.